# How do you write above and below in arrow in chemical reaction in word

Tags: microsoft-word, equations

I am trying to write the following chemical reaction in Word 365:

[image: Intended chemical reaction]

I tried the following method:

```
RNH_2[sp]\below(Alkylamine)[sp] \rightarrow[sp]\below(NaOH)[sp]\above(X_2)[sp]
```

where `[sp]` = space button on keyboard

But the result I got was this:

[image: Resulting chemical reaction]

Which is not what I had intended, as **x<sub>2</sub>** is not above the arrow.

Can someone please help me with this?